# Login com token de autenticação usando jquery e ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Eu estou me aventurando tentando fazer um login usando token para autenticação, usando jquery e ajax. Eu tenho a tela de usuario e senha com o botão de logar e uma outra tela onde tem uma tabela com informações para o usuario mexer. Quando eu clico no botão de login ele me retorna o nome do usuario, um token JWT e a expiração desse token.

O que eu estou tentando fazer é que ao clicar no login ele grave esse token no servidor e va direto para a tela com a tabela, levando o token com ele. Quando expirar o token ele vai mandar logar novamente. Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>Login</title>

<link href="index-css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index-css/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index-css/site_global.css?crc=444006867" />

</head>

<body>

<img src="imagens/telabg.jpg" alt="pontual-logo" />
<style>
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400%;
    }
</style>

<!-- BOX DE CADASTRO -->

<form action="https://www.teste.teste.com:3000/api/v1/sign-in " method="post" name="login" id="login">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-top">
            <p style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:160px; color:white; font-size: 150%;">Logar</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="input_text" name="name" placeholder="Usuário" value="pontual">

        <div class="container">

            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="input_text" placeholder="Senha" value="#P0ntu@l">
            <i id="eye" class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </div>

        <script>
            // script mostrar/ocultar senha
            var senha = document.getElementById('senha');
            var eye = document.getElementById('eye');

            eye.addEventListener('click', togglePass);

            function togglePass() {

                eye.classList.toggle('active');
                (senha.type == 'password') ? senha.type = 'text':
                    senha.type = 'password';
            }
        </script>

        <input type="hidden" class="input_text" name="type_login" id="type_login" value="service" />
        <div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="salvar" name="myButton" value="foo">Logar</button>

    </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```